# Oracle Subquery while using count and max with join

Tags: oracle, join, count, subquery, max

Table `COMPUTER`:

[image]

Table `SUPPLIER`:

[image]

how to display the building location that has the most computers?
i Have been trying several ways include subquery, joins, max, count but all not working and error keeps happending

The result i pursueing is

```
SUPPID SNAME           SADDRESS             MAKE                   COUNT(*)
```

---

```
   125 Apple Sdn.Bhd   18 Jalan Duta        Apple                         3
```

Comment: select c.suppid,s.sname,s.saddress,c.make, count(*)
from computer c join supplier s on c.suppid = s.suppid
group by c.suppid,s.sname,s.saddress,c.make;   --- 


this is the last free error code i get then everything i insert is a mess

Answer (score 0):

For example (where sample data is in lines #1 - 12; query you might be interested in begins at line #13):

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  computer (compid, make, suppid, locid) as
  4    (select 13323, 'IBM'  , 124, 333 from dual union all
  5     select 13324, 'Apple', 125, 444 from dual union all
  6     select 13325, 'Apple', 125, 444 from dual union all
  7     select 13326, 'Apple', 125, 444 from dual
  8    ),
  9  supplier (suppid, sname, saddress) as
 10    (select 124, 'IBM Sdn.Bhd'  , '15 Jalan Duta' from dual union all
 11     select 125, 'Apple Sdn.Bhd', '18 Jalan Duta' from dual
 12    ),
 13  comp_loc as
 14    -- number of computers per location; RNK = 1 shows location with most computers
 15    (select locid,
 16            rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rnk,
 17            count(*) cnt
 18     from computer
 19     group by locid
 20    )
 21  select distinct s.suppid, s.sname, s.saddress, c.make, l.cnt
 22  from supplier s join computer c on c.suppid = s.suppid
 23  join comp_loc l on l.locid = c.locid
 24  where l.rnk = 1;

    SUPPID SNAME         SADDRESS      MAKE         CNT
---------- ------------- ------------- ----- ----------
       125 Apple Sdn.Bhd 18 Jalan Duta Apple          3

SQL>
```

Comment: i think the 'locid' is not related to the answer since we could connect the 'saddress' using 'suppid' right?

Comment: If you want to return data as you posted in a question, then yes - you need LOCID because otherwise you don't know which row to fetch from the COMP_LOC CTE. At least, not in code I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle 12 and newer

```
select s.suppid, s.sname, s.saddress, c.make, count(1) 
  from COMPUTER c
  join SUPPLIER s
    on c.suppid = s.suppid
 group by s.suppid, s.sname, s.saddress, c.make
 order by count(1) desc
 fetch first 1 row only <-- this line will fetch you the top 1 line only
```

You might also use "fetch first 1 row with ties" to output all the top manufacturers if there are many of them having same "count". E.g If IBM and Appl were having same amount of lines

On Oracle version before 12 do the following:

```
select * 
  from (select s.suppid, s.sname, s.saddress, c.make, count(1) 
          from comps c
          join suppls s
            on c.suppid = s.suppid
         group by s.suppid, s.sname, s.saddress, c.make
         order by count(1) desc)
 where rownum = 1; <-- this line will get you the top 1 manufacturer only
```

PS. version of the oracle database can be obtained for example using:

```
select version from v$instance;
```

Comment: wow great answer but does this is possible with usage of max operator?

Comment: @feezadaisuke with max on what? I mean what column do you need to get the max value from?